# Can we connect azure kinect DK with Nvidia Jetson Tx2 development kit?

Tags: nvidia-jetson, azurekinect

Can we connect Microsoft's azure Kinect DK camera with Nvidia Jetson TX2 board DK together? Do these development kits support each other? Can we work on them?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but we are working on it. Is should be ready soon though.

You can see our ARM proposal here: https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/blob/develop/proposals/ARM-support.md